# Inherited Delphi 2007 Project and need to compile it

Tags: delphi, lazarus, delphi-2007, rad-studio, dcc32

I've spent quite a bit of time (nearly a full day at this point) trying to figure out how to get an IDE that can compile a Delphi 2007 project. I have only found solutions using the Delphi IDE (From RAD Studio, which has a license fee of $1,500-$4,000), or Lazarus (which apparently isn't really good for importing existing Delphi projects, just new ones).

At this point, I just need to confirm that I can compile the project. If I can do that then I could probably justify paying the license fee for RAD Studio.

My question is does anyone know if its possible to get the 2007 Delphi compiler from anywhere? Also, is there any free IDE that I can use for Delphi 2007? I called RAD Studio customer support about getting a trial, but they cannot give a trial for the 2007 version unless you purchase a license for the current version.

This project does come with makefiles to compile via the command line, but it errors when attempting to compile using v34 compiler that comes with the current trial version of RAD Studio (10.4). I believe these errors are caused because of the v34 compiler version not being for Delphi 2007, but I just need to confirm that and ideally compile it using the correct version (I think v16 or 17 of the compiler).

Does anyone with more experience in Delphi have any information about where I can get the previous versions of the compiler, or just information in general that could help me figure out how to compile this project without a RAD Studio license?

Comment: Note that new licenses include access to previous versions, https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/previous-versions which are not just trials.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to familiarize yourself with the site before you begin posting.

Comment: What errors do you get? Maybe you need additional components to perform a successful compile!

Answer (score 2):

> does anyone know if its possible to get the 2007 Delphi compiler from anywhere?

Not for free, no.  But licensed, yes.  See further below.

> is there any free IDE that I can use for Delphi 2007?

No.  But there is a *free* [Community Edition](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter) of the Delphi IDE <sup>1</sup>. You could then upgrade the D2007 project to 10.x.  But you will likely have to make tweaks to the code as well, since D2007 predates Delphi's [migration to Unicode](https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/migration-upgrade-center#unicode) in D2009.

<sup>1: at the time of this writing, the Community Edition is for Delphi 10.3 Rio. Though Delphi 10.4 Sydney has been released, a 10.4 Community Edition has not been released yet.</sup>

> I called RAD Studio customer support about getting a trial, but they cannot give a trial for the 2007 version unless you purchase a license for the current version.

Correct.  The latest Delphi version [includes licenses for past versions](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/previous-versions).  Once licensed, you can then login to https://members.embarcadero.com and download RAD Studio 2007 from the "My Registered User Downloads" section.

> This project does come with makefiles to compile via the command line, but it errors when attempting to compile using v34 compiler that comes with the current trial version of RAD Studio (10.4). I believe these errors are caused because of the v34 compiler version not being for Delphi 2007, but I just need to confirm that and ideally compile it using the correct version (I think v16 or 17 of the compiler).

Create a new project for the modern IDE, add the existing source files to the new project, then compile.  Or install a licensed D2007.

Comment: Thank you for the info. It sounds like RAD Studio may be the only licensed option as well, is that also correct? If not, are you aware of any alternatives that would work?

Comment: If you don't need C++, then you don't need the full RAD Studio, you can purchase just Delphi by itself.  But no, there are really no other alternatives.  Either you migrate the project to the latest Delphi, or you license the old Delphi, or you port the project to FreePascal/Lazarus.